# Using for loop to design adder in vhdl

Tags: for-loop, vhdl

I'm trying  to create an m bit adder by instantiating multiple copies of the n bit adder using for/generate loop. This is my code so far, it fails to simulate by giving the error:
"Line 44: Not all partial formals of a_n have actual". The n bit adder is declared as component, I have successfully tested it and it works. 
Please help by offering any suggestions to solve this problem

```
entity m_bit_adder is
generic (m : integer := 16; n : integer := 4);
    Port ( A_m : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (m-1 downto 0);
           B_m : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (m-1 downto 0);
           Cin_m : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Cout_m : out  STD_LOGIC;
           S_m : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (m-1 downto 0));
end m_bit_adder;

architecture Behavioral of m_bit_adder is

component n_bit_adder is
generic (n_number : integer := 4);
    Port ( A_n : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(n-1 downto 0);
           B_n : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(n-1 downto 0);
           Cin_n : in  STD_LOGIC;
           S_n : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(n-1 downto 0);
           Cout_n : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal sig_m : std_logic_vector (m downto 0);


begin

 m_bit_adder : for j in 0 to m-1 generate

 n_bit : n_bit_adder generic map (n_number => n)

 port map (  
                   A_n(n-1) => A_m(j),       
                 B_n(n-1)=> B_m(j),
                 S_n(n-1) => S_m(j),
                 Cin_n => sig_m(j),
                 Cout_n => sig_m(j+1)              
                );



end generate;
sig_m(0) <= Cin_m; 
Cout_m   <= sig_m(m);

end Behavioral;
```

This is my code for the n adder:

```
entity n_bit_adder is
generic (n : integer := 4);
    Port ( A_n : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(n-1 downto 0);
           B_n : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(n-1 downto 0);
           Cin_n : in  STD_LOGIC;
           S_n : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(n-1 downto 0);
           Cout_n : out  STD_LOGIC);
end n_bit_adder;
architecture Behavioral of n_bit_adder is

component adder 
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC;
           B : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           S : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Cout : out  STD_LOGIC);

end component;

signal sig_n : std_logic_vector (n downto 0);


begin

n_bit_adder : for i in 0 to n-1 generate
 one_bit : adder

 port map (  
                    A => A_n(i), 
                 B => B_n(i),
                 S => S_n(i),
                 Cin => sig_n(i),
                 Cout => sig_n(i+1)
                );            
end generate;

sig_n(0) <= Cin_n; 
Cout_n <= sig_n(n);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Out of interest, what's wrong with just using the `+` operator and getting the synthesiser to do the adding for you?

Comment: Why not use the existing adder and set the desired width in its generic?

Answer (score 0):

The `n_bit_adder` is instantiated using only a single bit of the formal side with `A_n(n-1)` in:

```
n_bit : n_bit_adder generic map (n_number => n)
  port map (  
    A_n(n-1) => A_m(j),       
    ....
```

But the component for `n_bit_adder` has as `std_logic_vector` for `A_n` with multiple bits in:

```
component n_bit_adder is
  generic (n_number : integer := 4);
    Port ( A_n : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(n-1 downto 0);
    ...
```

So for a `std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)` then `A_n(2 downto 0)` are not used on the formal side (left side) of the mapping, which is also what the error message says in "Not all partial formals of a_n have actual".

Note also, that it looks like different names `n_number` and `n` are used in component for generic and `std_logic_vector` length on ports.

Comment: yes, I can see what you mean, thank you. What syntax can I use though to access all the bits ? using downto is causing other errors. I'm just a begineer in VHDL, sorry

Comment: Update the mapping to be sure that all the bits in the `std_logic_vector` ports are mapped to actual signals or ports.  Depending on the use, it may be easier to declare a signal, and map to this, and then assign to the signal.